# refactoring binomial with negative power

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am reading Calculus Made Easy where in Chapter IV:
$$(x+dx)^{-2}$$ 
Is refactored as: 
$$x^{-2}\left(1+\frac{dx}x\right)^{-2}$$
Could someone give me an insight into this refactoring? I can see from this question [Negative Exponents in Binomial Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85708/negative-exponents-in-binomial-theorem) the equation $(a + b)^n = a^n(1 + \frac{b}{a})^n $ though I don't know if this rule has a name so that I may research it further.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+b)^n=\left(a\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)^n=(a)^n\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)^n=a^n\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)^n$$
In your question you have: $a=x$, $b=dx$ and $n=-2$

Answer (score 1):

No need for any sort of binomial theorem. Just factor out an $x$, as follows

$$(x+dx)^{-2} = (x(1+\frac{dx}{x}))^{-2} = x^{-2} (1+\frac{dx}{x})^{-2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$Write $(x+dx)^{-2}$ as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(x+dx)^{2}}$ and use your knowledge.